# How to pass variable from jquery to code in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

in my page i have an int variable name mySerial and i want to pass a value from a script

mySerial =ui.item.Serial is not working

Answer (score 4):

You could pass this variable as query string parameter to some controller action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySerial = '12345';
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Foo", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { mySerial: mySerial },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
</script>
```

and the `Foo` action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string mySerial)
{
    ... do something with the serial here
}
```

Another possibility is to perform a redirect if you don't want to use AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySerial = '12345';
    var fooUrl = '@Url.Action("Foo", "Home")';
    window.location.href = fooUrl + '?mySerial' + encodeURIComponent(mySerial);
</script>
```

Or maybe I misunderstood your question and you want to assign your javascript variable to some value coming from the view model? In this case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySerial = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MySerial));
</script>
```

Comment: My problem is that the variable is not exists in the java script,it exists in the page @{  int mySerial=0;}

Comment: @avi, in this case simply replace `Model.MySerial` in my example with `mySerial`.

Comment: Hey @DarinDimitrov... this was killing me... spent almost 1 hour trying to make the 'C#' string in my jQuery code encoded and finally found your answer with `encodeURIComponent`! I've been up-voting a lot of your answers! This one is no different. :D Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you could pass value from your jquery to controller action like this ...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var postdata  = { name: "your name", Age: "your age" };// you can pass control values 
    $.ajax({
        ur: /home/index,
        data: postdata,
        success: function(returndata)
             {
                // do something here for the return data...
              }
         });  
});
```

in your controller

```
public ActionResult PostedDAta(string myname, string myage)
{
            // do somethign here and return Json back to Jquery code
            return Json(data,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);  
}
```